# creating different screens in libgdx game

Tags: libgdx

I want to make a menu of 2 buttons(play, shop). The play button would start the game, and the shop button would open a screen, in which the player can choose his main character.

How can I do this?

Comment: Remember to accept an answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the libGDX wiki for various starter tutorials. Google would also definitely have helped you on this one.

What you need are a Game class and some Screen classes. You have a Screen for each screen of your game. Here's a guide on how to write a simple game with Screens.

[libGDX Wiki - Extending the simple game](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending%20the%20Simple%20Game)